# function to output pairwise of passed letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a Python function that can take in letters and output a pairwise comparison of the letter given.

So for example, if my function is named `pairwise_letters()`, then it should behave as follows:

```py
>>> pairwise_letters('AB')
AB

>>> pairwise_letters('ABC')
AB  BC
AC

>>> pairwise_letters('ABCD')
AB  BC  CD
AC  BD  
AD  

>>> pairwise_letters('ABCDE')
AB  BC  CD  DE
AC  BD  CE
AD  BE
AE

>>> pairwise_letters('ABCDEF')
AB  BC  CD  DE  EF
AC  BD  CE  DF
AD  BE  CF
AE  BF
AF

...
```

Comment: Have you seen [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) or [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) ?

Comment: Ah, wonderful, will check it out.

Comment: I don't see "comparisons"...

Comment: Is the triangular shape of the output a necessary part of the solution? Or do you just need to get all the pairs?

Comment: @KellyBundy question title edited. Thanks for the observation.

Comment: @Barmar not exactly, I would however wish it could be it that shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get each pairing. By default, `itertools.combinations()` outputs an iterable of tuples, which you'll need to massage a bit to turn into a list of strings:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def pairwise_letters(s):
    return list(map(''.join, combinations(s, 2)))
    
print(pairwise_letters("ABC"))
```

This outputs:

```py
['AB', 'AC', 'BC']
```

Comment: I love how you snuck in the bound method `''.join`!

Answer (score 0):

does this function behave as you expect?:

```
def pairwise_letters(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print(*[''.join(j) for j in zip(s, s[i+1:])], sep=' ')

pairwise_letters('ABCDEF')
'''
AB BC CD DE EF
AC BD CE DF
AD BE CF
AE BF
AF
```